# Ошибка:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Reader extends JFrame{
       JButton b1, b2;
       JLabel l1, l2, l3, l4;
       JTextField t1, t2;
       int i , k;
       String a , b;
       eHandler handler = new eHandler();

       public Reader(String s){
          super(s);
          setLayout(new FlowLayout());
          b1 = new JButton("Очистить");
          b2 = new JButton("Посчитать");
          l1 = new JLabel("Введите первое число");
          l2 = new JLabel("Введите второе число");
          l3 = new JLabel("");
          l4 = new JLabel("");
          t1 = new JTextField(10);
          t2 = new JTextField(10);
          add (b1);
          add (b2);
          add (l1);
          add (t1);
          add (l2);
          add (t2);
          add (l3);
          add (l4); 
          b2.addActionListener(handler);
          b1.addActionListener(handler);
     }
     public class eHandler implements ActionListener{
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
             try{      
                if(e.getSource()==b2){
                    i = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
                    k = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
                    i++;
                    k++;
                    a = "Ваше первое число теперь равно " + i; 
                    b = "Ваше первое число теперь равно " + k; 
                    l3.setText(a);
                    l4.setText(b);
                }
                if(e.getSource()==b1){
                    t1.setText(null);
                    t2.setText(null);
                    l3.setText(null);
                    l4.setText(null);
                }
    }catch (Exception ex) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Введите в поле число");}
}
```

Comment: а в чём состоит вопрос?

Comment: Пишет ошибку в самом конце , около знака }

Comment: @Кирилл, все просто же. "синтаксическая ошибка, вставьте **}**"

Answer (score 4):

В конце файла добавить 2 **}** надо

Comment: @Кирилл если ответ вам помог, то, по правилам хорошего тона принятым на  сайте, отметьте его галочкой как лучший